# Mute everyone in voice channel except certain roles

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to mute everyone but a certain role in a vc, I am able to mute the entire vc but I can't quite figure out how to unmute a specific role.

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('727646416834396171') || message.member.roles.cache.has('727646559675614325')) {
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channel.id);
            for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
                member.voice.setMute(true);
            }
        }
    } else {
        message.channel.send("You don't have permission to do that.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this where you can see if every user has the role, if they do not have either of the roles you can mute them but if they do it won't do anything to them!

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('727646416834396171') || message.member.roles.cache.has('727646559675614325')) {
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channel.id);
        for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
           if (!member.roles.has("First") && !member.roles.has("second role") {
             member.voice.setMute(true);
          }
        }
    }
} else {
    message.channel.send("You don't have permission to do that.");
}
```